# Living End/Living Death (EDH)

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-multiplayer

I have a [Mazirek, Kraul Death Priest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMazirek%2c%20Kraul%20Death%20Priest%5d) and [Yahenni, Undying Partisan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYahenni%2c%20Undying%20Partisan%5d) on the battlefield and I cast [Living End](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiving%20End%5d). Pretend every player has 5 creatures, and there are 4 players (including me).

Do the abilities of Mazirek or Yahenni trigger after the Living End resolves or do the abilities disappear?

For example:
I cast Living End and sacrifice five creatures including Mazirek/Yahenni my three opponents each sacrifice five creatures as well.

So do the abilities of Mazirek or/and Yahenni go on the stack and if so do they resolve and put counters on the appropriate creatures?

Comment: What do you mean by "do they get stacks"? Does who get what? Do you mean stacks of what, or do you mean to ask if something stacks with something else? Also, I've given your last sentence an edit to what I think you mean (i.e. it's two distinct sentences, not one).

Comment: @doppelgreener, thank you I edit it to make it clear.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble understanding some of the wording in the question, but it looks like just a language barrier issue.... if someone could edit for clarity that would be helpful. Especially "So goes the abillitie".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Mazirek, your creatures that started in your graveyard, and are placed on the battlefield by Living End would get 19 +1/+1 counters after Living End resolves.  The gatherer page even says:

> If a permanent is sacrificed to pay a cost of a spell or ability, Mazirek’s ability will resolve before that spell or ability. Conversely, if a permanent is sacrificed during the resolution of a spell or ability, that spell or ability will finish resolving before Mazirek’s ability is put onto the stack.

For Yahenni, the ability will trigger (and be put on the stack after Living End resolves), but won't do anything since Yahenni is no longer there.

> If Yahenni and a creature an opponent controls die simultaneously (perhaps because they fought or were in combat together), Yahenni won’t be on the battlefield as its triggered ability resolves. It can’t be saved by the +1/+1 counter that would have been put on it.

Comment: Do you mean the creatures that came onto the battlefield from the graveyard would get the counters?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yes.  They are "creatures you control" when Mazirek's ability resolves.

Comment: Ah ok, that's what I expected :-) Thought the current wording was a bit confusing because it says creatures in the graveyard get counters.

Answer (score 1):

Living End will resolve and the abilities from Mazirek and Yahenni will trigger.

With Mazirek's triggers, any creature returned to the battlefield by Living End (or put on the battlefield after the resolution of Living End and before the triggered abilities resolve) will get one +1/+1 counter for each creature sacrified.

Yahenni's triggers won't do anything since they are no longer on the battlefield.